# Null checks in user validation

Tags: javascript, validation

I would like to know an alternative, more elegant way to write the following method.  I am especially not enthusiastic of the nested `if` statement.

```
hasUserSavedCredentials: function () {
            var userName = Storage.get(CONFIG.app.storageUserName),
                password = Storage.get(CONFIG.app.storagePassword),
                result = false;
            if (userName !== null && password !== null) {
                if (userName.length > 0 && password.length > 0) {
                    result = true;
                    // save in state for faster retrivial
                    State.xx.isSaved = result;
                    State.xx.userName = userName;
                    State.xx.password = password;
                } else {
                    result = false;
                    State.xx.isSaved = false;
                }
            }
            return result;
        },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove `result = false;`, as `result` is already `false`.

And to get rid of the nested statements, you could use early returns:

```
if (userName == null && password == null) {
    return false;
}

if (userName.length <= 0 && password.length <= 0) {
    State.xx.isSaved = false;
    return false;
}
State.xx.isSaved = true;
State.xx.userName = userName;
State.xx.password = password;
return true;
```

Is it correct that when `username` is null, `isSaved = false` should not be set? Because if not, then you could just combine the two `if` statements, either in my example, or in yours.

Answer (score 1):

Seems kind of weird that you need to check `null` and `''` from the storage value.  You would think that if the storage kept a value that it would be valid.  If you can't change how that works the following code could avoid an extra if check and be a little more terse:

```
hasUserSavedCredentials: function () {
            var userName = Storage.get(CONFIG.app.storageUserName) || '',
                password = Storage.get(CONFIG.app.storagePassword) || '',
                hasSavedCredentials = userName.length > 0 && password.length > 0

                if (hasSavedCredentials) {
                    State.xx.userName = userName;
                    State.xx.password = password;
                }
                State.xx.isSaved = hasSavedCredentials;

            return hasSavedCredentials;
        }
```

I am assuming storage will either return null or a string if it is found, since it null is a falsy the `||` will default it to `''`.  The extra `if` can be avoided because username or password will always be a string.  Since there isn't an extra if check the result can be stored and used without the need for an else.  Also naming `result` to a more descriptive value helps.